# I Can't Get My String Equation Parser to Recognize and Incorporate Negative Numbers

Tags: c++, string, g++

I am back again and trying to simplify my code for this. Essentially I needed to write a calculator program that reads through and spits out the answer. Pemdas is not needed. The syntax for the string input is always going to be "x + y * z". My issue currently is that my program doesn't work correctly with negative operands. For example using "4 * -5" gives me 20. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

float process_func(string x);
bool isPartOfNum(char x);
void std_calc();


int main() {
    std_calc();     
    return 0;
}
/******************************************************
** Function: std_calc
** Description: loops through standard calculations
** Parameters: n/a
** Pre-Conditions: 
** Post-Conditions:
******************************************************/
void std_calc() {
    string x;
    float f;
    int y;
    cout << "input a string" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, x);
    f = process_func(x);
    cout << f << endl;

    cout << "Go again? 1 for yes, 0 for no" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    if (y == 1)
        std_calc();
}


/******************************************************
** Function: process_func
** Description: Takes an equation and splits into two lists
** Parameters: string
** Pre-Conditions: There is a single space between every number and operand
** Post-Conditions:
******************************************************/
float process_func(string x) {
    int end_of_num = 0, start_of_num = -1;// used to find last index from num  // used to hold start of each num
    list <float> numList;
    list <char> operList;

    if (x.length() == 0) {
        cout << "Empty string provided" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if (x.find_first_not_of("0123456789+*-/. ") != string::npos) {
        cout << "Invalid input string" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((x.at(0) < 48 || x.at(0) > 57) && x.at(0) != '-') { //check if start of string doesnt have a number or negative symbol
        cerr << "Improper input, use syntax: A + B" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    x.append(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        if (isPartOfNum(x.at(i))) {
            if (start_of_num == -1) {
                start_of_num = i;
                end_of_num = i;
            }
            end_of_num++;
        }
        else if (x.at(i) == ' ') {
            numList.push_back(stof(x.substr(start_of_num, end_of_num)));
            start_of_num = -1;
        }
        else if ((x.at(i) == '+' || x.at(i) == '-' || x.at(i) == '*' || x.at(i) == '/') && !isPartOfNum(x.at(i+1))) { //need to i++ in here to skip space
            operList.push_back(x.at(i));
            i++;
        }
    } //at this point both lists should be full of all needed pieces of info
    return process_lists(numList, operList);
}


/******************************************************
** Function: isPartOfNum
** Description: checks if the character is a part of a number
** Parameters: char
** Pre-Conditions:
** Post-Conditions:
******************************************************/
bool isPartOfNum(char x) {
    if ((x >= '0' && x <= '9') || ( x == '.'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

/*bool isPartOfNum(char x) {
    if ((x >= '0' && x <= '9') || (x == '.') || (x == '-'))
        return true;
    return false;
}
*/
```

The issue here has to do with isPartOfNum and how my numbers are read into the lists. I have already checked and the math part of my program isn't an issue so I omitted it from here. If isPartOfNum includes '-' then negative numbers work, as long as they are part of a number. For example "-5 * 4" gives me 20. But, "5 - 4" makes the program crash because it tries to use stof(string x) on " " which results in an invalid argument exception. As you can tell I left the isPartOfNum including '-' commented out.

On the contrary, if isPartOfNum doesn't include '-', then the program always starts reading when the digits starts even if there is a negative in front of it.

Comment: Pick any negative number. It can be -1. It can be -42. It can be -1843793245987. Now review your code that tries to figure out which parts of the input string consists of characters that compose a number, and keep staring at that part of your code until you figure out your bug. Oh, and by the way, this is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables, as they change, observe your program's behavior, and how it differs from the expected behavior. This is what a debugger is for.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to use the debugger with visual studio. But I will definitely try it out when I get back home

Comment: isPartOfNum() looks at a single character, and tries to determine if it is part of a number - but it can't do that correctly without knowing some context (information about the characters around the one that's being looked at.)  I'd suggest first splitting your line into "words" that don't contain whitespace, and then looking at each word to determine if it is a number or an operation.